# Dom Manipulation - Animation sequence on a visual element with content updating each cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic webpage that polls the backend for new/archived tweets. The returned tweets(JSON) are shown one at a time sliding into view from above the viewport, pausing at the middle and then sliding out below the viewport for the next tweet to display. Animation is via applying a Greensock tween to each tweet item and appending it to an animation timeline for playback.

**What are suitable ways to approach this correctly?** My main concerns are with how I should insert/update the DOM with the tweet items, and any performance issues I might need to be aware of or cater to(Memory / Layout / Rendering(CSS/Images)).

---

I am fairly new to web development. My current code uses *JQuery* to append each tweet into a container div, each tweet is positioned(`position:fixed`) outside of the viewport and `visibility:hidden`. I'm presently using embedded tweets with the twttr.js lib which is somewhat problematic due to several issues iframes cause. I plan to transition to my own html snippet + css/js instead.

With plain html or html from template engines like *Handlebars* or *Dust*, would it still be a good idea to insert the html for the tweet item like I'm currently doing with the iframe embeds approach? I've yet to use a template engine but understand they have a feature called *partials* that may be more useful than declaring the html and data logic all in my JS file?

The other concern I have is that as I append tweets currently, due to how the iframe embeds work they're a bit slow to render so need to be preloaded/added ahead of time, and remain in the DOM if manipulating the animation sequence timeline(rewind/fast-forward/scrubbing) due to having to reload again if added/removed. I've seen this cause performance issues with the smoothness of the animation as the amount of tweets in the DOM grows, in addition to memory I guess(not sure by how much).

Switching from using twitters iframe embeds(one per tweet) is probably going to make quite a difference in itself. Is it still a good idea to keep the added html for each tweet piling up? If I have the animation sequence add/remove/recycle(not sure if I'd benefit from an object pool?) the html for each tweet item, am I going to be causing layout/rendering all the time with the CSS as opposed to positioning off the viewport or toggling visibility/display properties? While I don't plan to match the iframe embeds display featureset, I would like to include photo's for the tweets that contain one, thus height would be variable.